# Why are images broken?

Tags: wordpress

I installed Wordpress on an Ubuntu 16.04 fresh image following the [official guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress). The installation went fine and the site is almost usable.

**The media part, however, is broken.**

The server is installed in `/var/www/html/wordpress`:

```
root@wp:/var/www/html# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Aug 27 22:00 index.html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    21 Aug 27 22:38 wordpress -> /usr/share/wordpress/
```

within this directory there is a wp-content one:

```
root@wp:/var/www/html# ls -l /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root 12288 Aug 27 22:03 languages
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data root  4096 Aug 27 22:03 plugins
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data root  4096 Aug 27 22:03 themes
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root  4096 Aug 27 22:32 uploads
```

The directories are full of various files, **except for uploads**, which is empty (after adding some media).

On the other hand, there is a place where Wordpress data is also present:

```
root@wp:/var/www/html# ls /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/
index.php  languages  plugins  themes  uploads
```

The `upload` directory is filled with the uploaded media.

There seems to be a disconnect between these two directories. The URL of the image, as seen by Wordpress, is (as an example) `http://10.20.5.2/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/minecraft.jpg`. This image is actually in `/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/minecraft.jpg`.

The guide mentions in the troubleshooting section

> This can also cause errors that prevent uploading media (like images)
>   or pictures that are uploaded but do not show correctly in your
>   browser.

Following the advice, I changed the data to

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/lib/wordpress/wp-content');
```

but this did not fix the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Added this and it worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content/uploads  /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads
```